# Pass parameter to a script function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner on this so please be patient with me. I have look up this problem and did not found a solution.
I have the following code:

on the head

```
<script>
   function ledonoff(led)
    {
     if (document.getElementById('ck1').checked == true){
      document.getElementById('led1').style.backgroundImage="url('Image/led_green.gif')";}
     else {
      document.getElementById('led1').style.backgroundImage="url('Image/led_red.gif');}
    }
</script>
```

on the body

```
<div id="led1"></div>

<input name="" type="checkbox" id="ck1" onchange="ledonoff('led1')" value=""/>
```

I will like to have the function ledonoff take 2 parameters to be used in function : div id to be changed 
and checkbox that is to be verified on the if of the function.
Can anyone help me with this.
Thank you

Comment: `</script>` at the beginning? That's probably the source of the problem.

Comment: You pass in a parameter, but never use it.

Comment: Take a look at arguments.length, I think this is your want if you want to overload that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the function to:

```
  function ledonoff(led,checkBox){
       var theDiv = document.getElementById(led),
           check = document.getElementById(checkBox);
       if (check.checked == true){
        theDiv.style.backgroundImage="url('Image/led_green.gif')";
       } else {
        theDiv.style.backgroundImage="url('Image/led_red.gif')";
      }
    }
```

and the htmlonchange to:

```
"ledonoff('led1','ck1')"
```

[in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/okiyer/4/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to:

```
<script>
function ledonoff(isChecked, elementId)
{
if (isCkecked){
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.backgroundImage="url('Image/led_green.gif')";}
else {
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.backgroundImage="url('Image/led_red.gif');}
}
</script>
```

And The body to:

```
<input name="" type="checkbox" id="ck1" onchange="ledonoff(this.checked, "led1")" value=""/>Led 1
```

Comment: Quite shorter with `document.getElementById(elementId).style.backgroundImage = "url('Image/led_" + (isChecked ? "green" : "red") + ".gif')";`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass it: `onchange="ledonoff('led1', 'ck1')"`.

However your function is expecting one argument, so you need to amend that.

```
function ledonoff(led) -> function ledonoff(led, ck)
```

**Just to note**

This type of JavaScript is called [Obtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). The recent shift in design principle is to have your Javascript and your HTML in completely separate files. Instead of assigning functions to events in an attribute fashion, you should use the `DOM` to add event listeners to `DOM` Elements. [Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/javascript-and-the-dom-series-lesson-1/) is a good tutorial to get you started on the idea.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
<script>
 function ledonoff(led,checkbox){
   if(document.getElementById(checkbox).checked == true){
    document.getElementById(led).style.backgroundImage="url('Image/led_green.gif')";
   }else{
    document.getElementById(led).style.backgroundImage="url('Image/led_red.gif')";
   }
 }
</script>
```

and your html:

```
<div id="led1"></div>
<input name="" type="checkbox" id="ck1" onchange="ledonoff('led1','ch1')" value=""/>Led1
```

i think, thats it. i assume your image paths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
</script>
 function ledonoff(led,chk)
 {
  if (document.getElementById(chk).checked == true){
   document.getElementById(led).style.backgroundImage="url('Image/led_green.gif')";}
  else {
   document.getElementById(led).style.backgroundImage="url('Image/led_red.gif');}
  }
</script>


<div id="led1"></div>

<input name="" type="checkbox" id="ck1" onchange="ledonoff('led1','ck1')" value=""/>Led 1
```